# In VS code, whenever I save a file in Html its being saved as Brave Html document when I actually want it to save as Chrome Html doc. How to do it?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Earlier I used to have Brave as my default browser and installed vs code using Brave browser. I then uninstalled vs code and reinstalled it from chrome browser. Still I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with VS Code, if it saves it as "something.html". It is about how the file association for *.html files is set in your operating system.

Comment: first of it is not `html` or `visual-studio-code` question. This may be in the category of `browser` and `windows`. A quick solution is `right-click` on your `html` file > go to properties > change the open with and select chrome as default or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Right click then click open with and choose more apps and select chrome then select always open with chrome and tada.